# Nested for-each on same list in Java?

Tags: java, list, foreach, iterator

I have a list of lists of Integer that I'm using to build chains based on an input file. The input specifies pairs (e.g. "3, 1" indicates that 1 replaces 3 in the application), and there are overlaps in the pairs (e.g. "3, 1" and "1, 4" would mean that 1 replaces 3 and 4 replaces 1, so ultimately, 4 replaces 3).

In order to reduce all of the pairs into their final chains, I have a list containing lists of all the pairs, and then I find which entries in the list overlap and append to the chains as needed, removing the pair that has been appended to another. This is how I am attempting to do this, but I know the failure is in doubling up the iterator references:

```
    for (ArrayList<Integer> outerChain : chains) {
        for (ArrayList<Integer> innerChain : chains) {
            if (outerChain.get(0).equals(innerChain.get(innerChain.size() - 1))) {
                outerChain.remove(0);
                innerChain.addAll(outerChain);
                chains.remove(outerChain);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As an example of the input/desired output from this operation:

```
    {<1,3>,<2,7>,<7,9>,<8,12>,<9,1>,<6,8>}
```

being individual lists corresponding to input pairs, the output would be:

```
    {<2,7,9,1,3>,<6,8,12>}
```

Is there a way I can nest iterators like this such that the references within each iterator are updated when removing or updating for one or the other?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I know it's not what you asked about, but why don't you do it with linear complexity? You could just make a array of "who is my direct replacement", find out which elements start chains (do not replace anything) and follow their chains using the values in the array.

Comment: Be careful comparing `Integers` with `==` - outside a narrow range (I think up to 128 or 256?) it will no longer return what you expect (just like string comparisons).

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski there will be multiple pairs that tag onto the end of a single chain at times, so if I store it off separate and don't update the list, then I may find (from the example above) that I get <2,7,9> and also <9,1,3>, but I would then need to go back over what I pull out to find that <2,7,9,1,3>.

Comment: @thegrinner I just threw that up there to put sample code up, but thanks for the heads up. I'll update it so it's not made an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So when should you use the for-each loop? Any time you can. It really
>   beautifies your code. Unfortunately, you cannot use it everywhere.
>   Consider, for example, the expurgate method. The program needs access
>   to the iterator in order to remove the current element. The for-each
>   loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove. Therefore, the
>   for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly it is not usable
>   for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you
>   traverse it. Finally, it is not usable for loops that must iterate
>   over multiple collections in parallel. These shortcomings were known
>   by the designers, who made a conscious decision to go with a clean,
>   simple construct that would cover the great majority of cases.

[(the For-Each Loop)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

You shouldn't use the for-each loop when you remove elements from the list or array while traversing it. Therefore you should use the explicit iterator syntax in your case.

Something like this :

```
Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = chains.iterator ();
while (outer.hasNext ()) {
    ArrayList<Integer> outerChain = outer.next();
    Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> inner = chains.iterator ();
    while (inner.hasNext ()) {
        ArrayList<Integer> innerChain = inner.next();
        if (outerChain.get(0).equals(innerChain.get(innerChain.size() - 1))) {
            outerChain.remove(0);
            innerChain.addAll(outerChain);
            outer.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you modify a list in an iterator you can't use that iterator.  Fortunately you need to start again anyway so you have a natural solution

```
OUTER: while(chains.size() > 1) {
    for (ArrayList<Integer> outerChain : chains) {
            for (ArrayList<Integer> innerChain : chains) {
                if (outerChain.get(0) == innerChain.get(innerChain.size() - 1)) {
                    outerChain.remove(0);
                    innerChain.addAll(outerChain);
                    chains.remove(outerChain);
                    continue OUTER;
                }
            }
        }
    break; // no more matches found.
}
```

Comment: The problem with this type of approach though is that I do not delete all entries. In the end, there are still chains left, they are just the completed ones, so working off your while condition, the system would never terminate.

Comment: The system will terminate on the `break;` which will be performed if there was no matches.

Comment: Ye-olde Visual Basic 3 GoTo.   Dude, stick to structured programming please.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem with double for-each-loops, but I see a big problem with `==` operator, which you are using for comparing `Integer` objects. This is totally incorrect. You should use `.equals()` method instead.

Answer (score -1):

use this as a guide:

```
    for(int[] i: sampleIntArray)
    {
        for(int current: i)
        {
            //sample code here;
        }
    }
```